# Drag and Drop aimlessly in WPF Desktop applications

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm finding it extremely difficult to drag and drop any control (and I plan to allow ANY control) to be dragged and dropped in my app without having a Drop target or whatever. I just want to be able to drag any control from, say, here... to "over there somewhere". But this doesn't seem possible. Is this possible? You can implement drag and drop in WinForms with just a few lines of code, how do we have this same drag and drop support in WPF?

Comment: Are you looking to freely reposition (move) controls on a canvas, or do you really want "drag and drop"?  Drag and Drop implies that you have a drag target and a drop target, for example, moving a List Item from one list to another, or re-ordering items in a list.  If you're just seeking to allow the user to reposition controls on a window, that is a different operation.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I want to just move a controls from one position on the window to another position. Regardless of where it came from. I don't want to drag list items (but I do want to drag a whole ListView control.

Comment: I am confused by this in WPF because in WinForms we just need to handle the MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp events for the controls we want to move at runtime. But many controls do not have these events in WPF.

Comment: See my answer below.  The key is to use the `Canvas` that allows free-form positioning of child controls.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing in the question and the clarifying comments is more about repositioning elements than dragging and dropping.

This type of activity is fairly easy in WPF, the only consideration is the Layout Panel that houses the elements.  Because WPF tries to provide more structure around Layout (with `Grids`, `StackPanels`, etc.) you need a panel that will allow for free-form positioning of elements.  This calls for the `Canvas`.

So if you have a `Canvas` with elements on it (positioned with the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` for example), you can use the `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` and `MouseUp` to allow users to drag/reposition elements across the canvas.